# Popover not hide when hovering over it

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

Currently i have the following structure

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger={["hover", "focus", "click"]} placement="bottom" overlay={(
         <Popover className="timeline-popover-container" id="tpc-1">
             <TimelinePopover
                 alert={session}
                 previousAlert={prevSession}
                 nextAlert={nextSession}
                 status={status}
             />
         </Popover>
     )}>
         <div className="myclass">
             <div>{img}</div>
         </div>
     </OverlayTrigger>
```

So, when the popover is triggered and i try to hover over the popover, the popover dissapear.
I want to be able to click inside de popover, do things inside of that and just dissapear when i move the mouse out of it.

Comment: how do you want to trigger the popover? - what happens if you remove `focus` and `click` from the `trigger` list? (i.e. make the trigger list look like this instead: `trigger={["hover"]}` )

Comment: I want the popover to be triggered by hover, or clicking on the element. Removing that and keeping just hover does not change anything.

Comment: I think you are looking at what docs call "click w/root close" (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers-trigger-behaviors) - unfortunately, it seems like you have to choose between triggering by click (and get the desired behaviour) or hover (once you mouseout of an element you are no longer hovering it so if this is the trigger for showing the popover, then it is also the trigger for hiding it) - I do not think you'll be able to have both (w/o writing the code yourself) - In other words, you will have to choose

Comment: Alright @ochi thanks. Do you know any other option that me allow to do that?

Comment: What do you mean? I think you can either write the code yourself (I wouldn't know where to start) or use 'click w/rootClose' as the trigger (if you choose this, see my answer)

Comment: I am not sure if the option to `mouseenter` exists (as one of the triggers) - you could try that too!? - or write your own? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163137/react-bootstrap-popover-on-hover-closes-when-mouse-enters-popover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to make that work using one of the comments that ochi posted.

```
 <OverlayTrigger trigger={["hover"]} placement="bottom" overlay={(
    <Popover onMouseOver={this.showOverlay} onMouseOut={this.hideOverlay}>
        content
    </Popover>
 )}>
    <div onMouseOver={this.showOverlay} onMouseOut={this.hideOverlay}>
        <div>bla bla bla</div>
    </div>
 </OverlayTrigger>
```

adding trigger on the popover and on the div i want to trigger worked.

Answer (score 3):

I did a little component to handle this use case (inspired from the answer by @AnnieP).
https://gist.github.com/lou/571b7c0e7797860d6c555a9fdc0496f9

Usage:

```
<PopoverStickOnHover
  component={<div>Holy guacamole! I'm Sticky.</div>}
  placement="top"
  onMouseEnter={() => { }}
  delay={200}
>
  <div>Show the sticky tooltip</div>
</PopoverStickOnHover>
```

Comment: This worked great for me, did the job except that the popover gets "caged" in it's mother component, and I wanted it to be rendered more to the side, like that documentation example with container and containerPadding. Does anyone knows how to implement this?

Comment: Nvm I just tried to create my own component by copying AnnieP's answer. Worked fine =)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to do the same thing using React Bootstrap except with a tooltip instead of a popover. The answer here gave me a good jumping off point, which I mixed with the [Custom Overlay](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#custom-overlays) example in the React Bootstrap docs.

I replaced `OverlayTrigger` with a custom `Overlay`, which wraps the `Tooltip` but is outside of the target element, whereas the `OverlayTrigger` wraps the target element and calls `Tooltip` through the `overlay` prop. I added `onMouseEnter()` and `onMouseLeave()` to both the tooltip and the target element to toggle the tooltip visibility state so that leaving either one will close the tooltip.

This is a bare-bones version of my implementation:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Tooltip, Overlay } from 'react-bootstrap';

const TooltipExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showTooltip: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    let myTooltip = (
      <Tooltip 
        onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ showTaskTooltip: true })}
        onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ showTaskTooltip: false })}
      >
        I'm a tooltip and I'll stay open when you leave the target element and hover over me!
      </Tooltip>
    );

    return(
      <div>
        <h3
          ref="target"
          onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ showTooltip: true })}
          onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ showTooltip: false })}
        >
          Hover over me!
        </h3>

        <Overlay
          show={this.state.showTooltip}
          onHide={() => this.setState({ showTooltip: false })}
          placement="bottom"
          target={() => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.target)}
        >
          {myTooltip}
        </Overlay>
      </div>
    );
  }  
}

export default TooltipExample;
```

Comment: Ended up using this (with a functional component and `useState()`) to solve a problem where the overlay is intended to appear _inside_ the target element. Worked great! Thanks for your post.